# Estimating variance of MLE estimate of Beta-Geometric/NBD without MCMC

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, customer-lifetime-value

I'm using Fader's [BG/NBD](http://brucehardie.com/papers/bgnbd_2004-04-20.pdf) model for customer LTV calculations. The log likelihood is the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \ln L(r, \alpha, a, b|X_i=x_i, t_{x_i}, T_i) = \frac{B(a, b + x)}{B(a, b)}\frac{\Gamma(r + x)\alpha^r}{\Gamma(r)(\alpha + T)^{r+x}} + \delta_{x>0}\frac{B(a+1, b + x-1)}{B(a, b)}\frac{\Gamma(r + x)\alpha^r}{\Gamma(r)(\alpha + T)^{r+x}}
$$

It's trivial to use any solver to find estimates for $(r,\alpha, a, b)$ that minimize the log likelihood. However, I'm interested in the variance around each estimate. Short of running an MCMC, can anyone point me to how I could derive or simulate the variance for each estimate?

Answer (score 1):

the estimated standard errors of the maximum likelihood estimates are the square roots of the diagonal elements of the inverse of the Hessian matrix.  If you use an optimizer in R, you should be able to obtain the Hessian.